# SQLAlchemy argument error: ondelete undefined

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table where there is a `User` table and a `Follow` table. The follow table has two foreign keys which refer to the user's `id` who follows and the user who's being followed `id`.

If a user was to delete their account, I would like all the records in the following table to be deleted along with the User record. The way I thought to do this was by using `onupdate='CASCASE', ondelete='CASCASE'` like so:

```
follower = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'), onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE')
following = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'), onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE')
```

I try to update my database (using Flask-Migrate/Alembic) however, I receive the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['ondelete']
```

So it appears `onupdate` works fine but not `ondelete`.

Why do I have this issue and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onupdate` and `ondelete` are parameters for the `ForeignKey` constructor, not the `Column` constructor. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.

The `Column` constructor does have an `onupdate` parameter which is why it seemed to work, but what you are looking for is the `ForeignKey` `onupdate` and `ondelete` parameters.

It should look like this:

```
follower = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'))
following = ...
```